# Error reading repository: QGIS Official Repository HTTP request failed

Tags: qgis-plugins

I can't seem to access the plugin repository.

Is this an issue with my system or is there something going on at the server end?!

I get the following error as wells sometimes a window saying: "Error reading repository: QGIS Official Repository
HTTP request failed"

It's snowing like crazy here and that often messes with the internet but every thing else seems to be working fine.

Comment: I just checked and I am getting the same error on both my desktop and my laptop.

Comment: iam getting the same error too. Be patient, will surely come up soon. Nevertheless i'm asking myself if it was a good decision of the qgis team to centralize the netload on the plugins.qgis server by removing all third party dependencies by default on new releases

Comment: And we're back in business. Thanks to @Curlew for confirming that I'm not going crazy at this end.

Comment: In the case that this issue comes up again are there mirror repositories hosting where the plugins can be downloaded from?

Comment: sadly not. In the past some plugins were hosted on third-party servers (mostly from qgis developers). However i reinstalled my system last week and also lost those links.